# How to retrieve and save to Blob a binary file video from Flask?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, axios, blob

I know few things about video encoding and I encountered an issue that is blocking me for few days.

**Goal:**

1. Record a video from my laptop's webcam with a VueJS front end application.
2. Send this video to a Python flask app in the backend within a FormData through Axios and Flask.
3. Receive the video in the Flask app.
4. Simply send back the video to the frontend with a Flask response (without applying any changes to the video).
5. Store and display this video on front end side.

**Code:**

1. By default, ev element type is: "video/x-matroska;codecs=avc1", I do not choose it.

```js
// Start webcam stream
startCameraStream() {
    const windowConstraints = (window.constraints = {
        audio: false,
        video: true
    });
    navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia(windowConstraints)
        .then(stream => {
            this.$refs.webcamStream.srcObject = stream;
        }).catch(error => {
            alert("Browse doesn't support or there is some errors." + error);
        });
},

// Stop webcam stream
stopCameraStream() {
    let tracks = this.$refs.webcamStream.srcObject.getTracks();
    tracks.forEach(track => {
        track.stop();
    });
},

// Start to record webcam and save it into chunks array and create a blob object
startRecordCameraStream(stream) {
    this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

    this.mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (ev) => {
        this.chunks.push(ev.data);
    };

    this.mediaRecorder.onstop = () => {
        this.blob = new Blob(this.chunks, {
            'type': "video/x-matroska;codecs=avc1"
        });
        this.chunks = [];
    };
    this.mediaRecorder.start();
},

// Stop to record webcam 
stopRecordCameraStream() {
    this.mediaRecorder.stop();
},
```

The blob file is readable and I am able to display it with these few coding lines:

```js
let videoURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.blob);
let vidSave = this.$refs.webcamRecord;
vidSave.src = videoURL;
```

2. I send the blob within a formData with the key 'webcam' and send it on Flask url with axios

```js
submitVideo(state, blob) {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('webcam', blob);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/', formData, { 
                headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                }
            }).then((response) => {
                // TOO SEE IN STEP 5
                resolve();
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error)
        }
    });

}
```

3. On the flask app, the formData has been sent and received and we are able to save and read the video on the backend side showing that everything is working well.

```py
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_cors import CORS
import flask

#Instance of Flask class
app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})

#Route function
@app.route('/', methods=["POST","GET"])
def model():
    if request.method == "POST":
        video = request.files['webcam'].stream.read()
        return flask.Response(video, mimetype='video/x-matroska')
```

I simply return back the binary object from Python to the VueJS frontend:

4. video is a python bytes object which looks like this:

```py
b'\x1aE\xdf\xa3\xa3B\x86\x81\x01B\xf7\x81\x ... '
```

We simply return this bytes object in a flask response:

```py
return flask.Response(video, mimetype='video/x-matroska')
```

5. We received the flask response and store it in a blob file (response part from point 2)

```js
}).then((response) => {
    let data = response.data;
    let video = new Blob([data],{'type': "video/x-matroska;codecs=avc1;"})
    state.modelVideo = video;
    resolve();
})
```

Once, we try to display the blob as explain in point 1, nothing happens:

```js
let videoURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.modelVideo);
let vidSave = this.$refs.webcamRecord;
vidSave.src = videoURL;
```

Something really strange is that the initial and new blob files do not have the same size and when we read binary from both blob object we have this:

Initial blob binary from frontend (with a FileReader and readAsBinaryString function) :

```py
"\u001aEß££B†\u0001B÷\u0001Bò\u..."
```

Received blob binary from backend (with a FileReader and readAsBinaryString function):

```py
"\u001aEß£ï¿½Bï¿½ï¿½\u0001Bï¿½ï¿½\..."
```

**Opinion:**

My thought is that when sending back video from backend side, there is an encryption misunderstanding between Python and Javascript. I tried to encode in base64 on backend side and decode on frontend side but nothing changes.

The raw data response I received from backend is:

```json
{
    "data": "\u001aEߣ�B��\u0001B��\u0001B��..."
    "status": 200,
    "statusText": "OK",
    "headers": {
        "content-length": "15661",
        "content-type": "video/x-matroska"
    },
    "config": {
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:5000/",
        "method": "post",
        "data": {},
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
        },
        "transformRequest": [
            null
        ],
        "transformResponse": [
            null
        ],
        "timeout": 0,
        "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
        "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "maxContentLength": -1,
        "maxBodyLength": -1
    },
    "request": {}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add responseType blob to request init option:

```js
axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/', formData, { 
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  },
  responseType: 'blob' // default is "json"
})
```